# What does it mean to send a photon somewhere while another "remains behind"?

Tags: photons, quantum-entanglement, quantum-teleportation

Today this article appeared in the news, describing an experiment lead by Dr Wolfgang Tittel at University of Calgary, involving information teleportation via photons:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-37408013

The article attempts to describe the process by claiming that two photons are created and then (emphasis added):

> One of these photons is sent in a "classical" way along 11.1km of
>   optical fibre to a building near Calgary City Hall (C in the photo),
>   ***while the other remains behind at the university***.

I realise that a media article is unlikely to do a good job of translating physics to layman's terms, but I can't figure out what they actually meant by this.

How is it possible for a photon to "remain behind" (implying that it is not moving)? Alternatively, what is the proper explanation for what happened in this experiment?

Comment: I think it means that the second photon is kept trapped in a small region with some device (mirrors or something similar...), so it can still move.

Comment: I don't know in this specific case, but a typical way is to feed it into a 10-km optical fiber which is rolled up in the lab.  Alternatively, one can measure it right away (depending on what one wants to do with it).